Allowing only specific types of objects(image/jpeg) to be transferred during GCP GCS transfer job creation
I want to create a GCS transfer job which transfer only certain type of objects let us say (image/jpeg) only between 2 GCS buckets.
I can't see any way to do it now as there is only prefix match support via the GCP console. Is it not possible?

This is not possible according to the current GCP transfer job documentation and support team.
But there are 2 alternatives possible.

Filter by prefix - https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/filtering-objects-from-transfers
Transferring specific objects between buckets - https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/manifest

